# SSIS/C#: Script Task, C# script to look at directory and store the name of 1 file in a variable

Tags: ssis

Basically I've written a C# script for a Script task in SSIS that looks in a User::Directory for 1 csv, if & only if there is one file, it stores that in the instance variable which then maps to the package variables of SSIS.

When I exicute, it gives me the red filled in box of the Script task. I think it's related to how I'm looking at the directory, but I'm not sure.

Please help!

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ST_e8b4bbbddb4b4806b79f30644240db19.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
       private String fileName = "";
       private String RootDirictory;
       private String FilePath;

       enum ScriptResults
       {
           Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
           Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
       };

       public ScriptMain()
       {
           RootDirictory = Dts.Variables["RootDir"].Value.ToString();
           FilePath = RootDirictory + "\\" + "SourceData" + "\\";
       }

       public void setFileName()
       {
           DirectoryInfo YDGetDir = new DirectoryInfo(FilePath);
           FileInfo[] numberOfFiles = YDGetDir.GetFiles(".csv");

           if (numberOfFiles.Length < 2)
           {
               fileName = numberOfFiles[0].ToString(); 
           }

          int fileNameLen = fileName.Length;

          String temp = fileName.Substring(0, fileNameLen - 5);

          fileName = temp; 
       }


       public void mapStateToPackage()
       {
           if((fileName!=null)||(fileName!=""))
           {
               Dts.Variables["ExDFileName"].Value = fileName; 
           }
       }

        public void Main()
        {
            setFileName();
            mapStateToPackage(); 
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could simply be done using `Foreach loop container` as explained in [**this Stack Overflow question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229597/ssis-get-any-flat-file-source-from-folder-and-cache-the-name-as-a-super-global-v), which was asked by you. :-)

Anyway, to answer your question with respect to `Script Task code` that you have provided. Below mentioned reasons could be cause of the issues:

1. You are looking for `.csv`. This won't return any results because you are looking for a file with no name but extension `.csv`. The criteria should be ***.csv**
2. If you are looking for exactly one file, then the condition `if (numberOfFiles.Length < 2)` should be changed to `if (numberOfFiles.Length == 1)`
3. The section of code after the **if** section which extracts the file name should be within the above mentioned **if** condition and not out side of it. This has to be done to prevent applying substring functionality on an empty string.
4. Modified code can be found under the **Script Task Code** section.

Sorry, I took the liberty to simplify the code a little. I am **not suggesting** this is the best way to do this functionality but this is `merely an answer` to the question.

Hope that helps.

**Script Task Code:**

**C#** code that can be used only in **`SSIS 2008 and above`**.

```
/*
   Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Task
   Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
   The ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.
*/
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ST_3effcc4e812041c7a0fea69251bedc25.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        Variables varCollection = null;
        String fileName = string.Empty;
        String fileNameNoExtension = string.Empty;
        String rootDirectory = string.Empty;
        String filePath = string.Empty;

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        public void Main()
        {
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::RootDir");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::ExDFileName");
            Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref varCollection);

            rootDirectory = varCollection["User::RootDir"].Value.ToString();
            filePath = rootDirectory + @"\SourceData\";

            DirectoryInfo YDGetDir = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
            FileInfo[] numberOfFiles = YDGetDir.GetFiles("*.csv");

            if (numberOfFiles.Length == 1)
            {
                fileName = numberOfFiles[0].ToString();
                fileNameNoExtension = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.LastIndexOf("."));
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileNameNoExtension))
            {
                varCollection["User::ExDFileName"].Value = fileNameNoExtension;
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```