# SSIS: download unknown name file from Sharepoint folder

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, wget

I`ve tried to download excel file in SSIS (Execute Process Task) from sharepoint by using wget but problem is that the excel file name can be different in next month so I want to create something like: download all file from SH folder (there will be only 1) and save it as xxx. In argument I tried something like this:

```
--user=xxx --password=xxx -a.xlsx (I tried also with -r -np -nd) "source path" -O "destination path"
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

I will be grateful for help

Comment: Is at least part of the file name known? A simple solution might be to use a Foreach Loop (works for one file just as well as multiple) and pattern match the file name. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229597/ssis-get-any-flat-file-source-from-folder-and-cache-the-name-as-a-super-global)

Comment: Great! This is the solution what I'm looking for!